# TC962 not inverting

Tags: charge-pump

I have a PCB which uses a TC962 to convert +3 V to -3 V so that I can use a split supply for an op-amp; however, I see ~Vdd at Vout when I have the TC962 on the PCB but it works fine when I desolder it, stick it on a breadboard, and build the test circuit from the datasheet (i.e. I supply +3 V to Vdd and see -3 V at Vout).

My configuration is shown below:
[image: circuit layout]

I confirmed that there isn't major damage to the TC962 by testing it on a breadboard; I assume this excludes latch-up as well, since the output from my REG1117 looks pretty clean (I tested with the REG1117 outputting ~2.8 V to be safe). I checked that the op amp (AD820) pins aren't shorted anywhere; I also desoldered the AD820 and breadboard tested, it worked fine as a unity gain voltage follower. I've also used this subcircuit before in other designs and it worked alright, so I didn't assume the overall design was wrong, but I am using a slightly different capacitance at the REG1117A output than I did before (I'm using the appropriate 10 uF now, whereas I accidentally used 100 pF before).

Any ideas on why the TC962 won't invert would be much appreciated!

**Edit, 6/13**

I do have a clue here: if I use a bench DC supply straight to the TC962 instead of supplying the current from a function generator, through my rectifier/doubler, and through the REG1117, the inversion works properly above ~3.1 Vdc. The REG1117 should be able to supply nearly 1 A, the TC962 only requires ~200 uA to function, and the GW-Instek AFG-2125 sig gen I'm using as a supply should be able to provide plenty of current, so I don't think current is a problem. However, the DC supply only has two digits for it's current output so it looked like I was drawing ~10 mA of current at 3.2 V. I also have an LTC6990 VCO on the same REG1117 output but that should draw, at the most, about 300 uA (according to the datasheet).

**Edit 2**

If I lift off the REG1117 output and have it supply te board, or use a DC bench supply, the TC962 and AD820 only draw 2 mA either way. That's a little high per their datasheets but are still easily supplied. So neither current supply nor voltage levels are the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your implementation has the connection to the zener diode on pin 1, it is not shown in the schematic above. It looks like they recommend a 690Ω resistor.

[image]

Comment: I ran a previous version without any connection to the zener diode reference pin but I suppose it can't hurt to try; I will run a jumper wire on the PCB tomorrow with that load or whatever 0805 resistor I have that's close in value.

Comment: I had a  680 so I put that between pins 1 and 8. No luck, unfortunately. I now have +2.8 V at Vdd and +1.8 V at Vout. Still no inverting.